# Chrome Extension - get all cookies for a specific tab - is it correct?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, session-cookies, cookiestore

I'm trying to get all cookies for a particular tab.

The trouble I'm having, and bear with me because I'm no cookie expert, the cookies I get from all the different methods are different / incomplete.

---

**Method 1:**

`document.cookie` - the way I understand it, those are the cookies that are associated with the document. In other words, I load a URL in chrome, in the Network tab I see there was a document requested for the URL I'm loading. In the request headers I can see cookies.

For some reason, though, the cookies I see in the request headers are different to what `document.cookie` will print. Also, when I check DevTools - Application - Cookies, there are a lot more cookies compared to `document.cookie`.

---

**Method 2:**

I came across a reply from mr. [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) - [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50099635/4017077):

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
  code: 'performance.getEntriesByType("resource").map(e => e.name)',
}, data => {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError || !data || !data[0]) return;
  const urls = data[0].map(url => url.split(/[#?]/)[0]);
  const uniqueUrls = [...new Set(urls).values()].filter(Boolean);
  Promise.all(
    uniqueUrls.map(url =>
      new Promise(resolve => {
        chrome.cookies.getAll({url}, resolve);
      })
    )
  ).then(results => {
    // convert the array of arrays into a deduplicated flat array of cookies
    const cookies = [
      ...new Map(
        [].concat(...results)
          .map(c => [JSON.stringify(c), c])
      ).values()
    ];

    // do something with the cookies here
    console.log(uniqueUrls, cookies);
  });
});
```

The way I understand mr. wOxxOm's reply is that it gets all the cookies from all the requests that were made when loading a URL in the particular tab.

Again, when I compare what I get from the code above, it differs to what I see in DevTools - Application - Cookies.

Maybe it is because some cookies are set using JS after the page is loaded and hence were not part of the requests made when loading the original URL?

---

**Method 3:**

Then there is `chrome.cookies.getAll`, But it gets all the cookies stored in chrome. And if I understand correctly, this is the reason for the Method 2 solution. If we get ALL the cookies, we don't know which tab they belong to, since a single tab can save cookies for multiple domains.

I found a [comment from mr. wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59650682/chrome-extension-running-in-incognito-not-retrieving-cookies-for-that-cookie-sto#comment105464180_59650682) which explains how to identify incognito cookieStore and to me it seems like this is the only solution that truly gets you all the cookies saved for a particular tab and should hopefully match what is displayed in DevTools - Application - Cookies.

By using a single tab in incognito mode, we're basically isolating that tab's cookies from the rest and hopefully covering all of them.

Something along the lines of:

1. Open Incognito window
2. Browse a URL (and do stuff, ie log in etc.)
3. Find out what cookieStore ID the tab belongs to
4. Use `chrome.cookies.getAll` to get all the cookies for that particular cookieStore

Something along the lines of:

```
// get current tab (my extension will work by clicking the extension icon, so popup.html/popup.js)
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var currTab = tabs[0];
    if (!currTab["incognito"]) { // If it's not an incognito tab, stop here
        console.log("current tab is not incognito");
    }
    else { // If it is an incognito tab, return tabId
        console.log(currTab["id"]);
    }
});

// Check cookieStoreId based on the tabId
chrome.cookies.getAllCookieStores(function (cookiestores){
    var cookieStore = cookiestores.find(obj => {
        return obj.tabIds.includes(tabId);
    });
    console.log(cookieStore["id"]);
});

get all cookies based on cookieStoreId
chrome.cookies.getAll({"storeId": "1"},function (cookie){
    console.log(cookie)
});
```

---

Are my assumptions correct? Is Method 3 really the only way to get all the cookies for a specific tab?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turned out to be a permissions issue. I needed to request `"<all_urls>"` host permission to be able to see ALL cookies. Without it I only saw a portion of the cookies.

Manifest v3:

```
    "host_permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
```

If you are interested in the script I wrote to get all cookies for a specific tab you will need the scripting and cookies permission.

```
    "permissions": [
        "cookies",
        "scripting"
    ]
```

My script, which is based on @wOxxOm's script, gets all cookies for the specified tab and deletes them:

```js
/* eslint-disable */

const tabId = 114632975;

function getPerformanceEntries() {
    return performance
        .getEntriesByType('resource')
        .map(
            (r) => r.name
        );
}

const results = await chrome.scripting.executeScript(
    {
        target: { tabId },
        func: getPerformanceEntries
    }
);

const resourceUrls = results[0].result;

const origins = resourceUrls
    .map((url) => new URL(url).origin)
    .filter((url) => Boolean(url) && url !== 'null');

const uniqueOrigins = new Set(origins);

const getCookiesPromises = [];

for (const url of uniqueOrigins) {
    const promise = chrome.cookies
        .getAll(
            {
                url
            }
        )
        .then(
            (cookies) => (
                {
                    url,
                    cookies
                }
            )
        );

    getCookiesPromises.push(promise);
}

const urlCookies = await Promise.all(getCookiesPromises);

const filtered = urlCookies.filter((c) => c.cookies.length);

console.log('Found Cookies:', filtered);

console.log('Total Cookie Count:', filtered.reduce((acc, c) => acc + c.cookies.length, 0));

const deletePromises = [];

for (const { url, cookies } of filtered) {
    for (const cookie of cookies) {
        const promise = chrome.cookies.remove(
            {
                url,
                name: cookie.name,
                storeId: cookie.storeId
            }
        );

        deletePromises.push(promise);
    }
}

await Promise.all(deletePromises);
```